# Main Loop for pygame doesn't work, pygame quits instantly

Tags: python, module, pygame

I have another issue. When I try to to run my code, pygame launches and then stops immediately.

Here's my code :

```
import pygame
import os 
import time 
import random

pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()




def main():

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    win = pygame.display.set_mode((Win_Width, Win_Height))

    run = True
    while run:

        clock.tick(40)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                pygame.quit()
```

Thank you to help me. Bye !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to call main()

so :

`if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()`

Answer (score 3):

Your pygame loop is contained within the method `main`. But `main` is never called anywhere. Consider adding the following block to the very bottom of your file

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

this block is basically just checking if you are calling this file directly, and if so, calling your `main` method.

Core taxxe's answer does a great job explaining this functionality of python in greater detail

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I'm not allowed to comment yet, though I will answer your question this way.

Before executing code, the Python interpreter reads a source file and defines a few special variables/global variables.
If the python interpreter is running that module (the source file) as the main program, it sets the special `__name__` variable to have a value “**main**”. If this file is being imported from another module, `__name__` will be set to the imported module’s name. The module’s name is available as the value of the `__name__` global variable.

In your case you could run your code either with an `if` etc. or with a direct `main()` call.

```py
print "Always executed"

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    print "Executed when invoked directly"
else: 
    print "Executed when imported"
```

I hope that was understandable and helpful.
For further information here are a few sources:

- [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-does-the-if-**name**-**main**-do](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-does-the-if-__name__-__main__-do)
- [What does if __name__ == "__main__": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)